# VBA what to dimension a variable when it can take value of a string or number (single/double)

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have created a macro that I use for bilinear interpolation and it works fine, however, I want to generate error outputs i.e. "Error: y and x outside of table range" to do this I have done:

```
Static Function biinterp(x As Double, y As Double, xrng As Range, yrng As Range, zrng As Range) As Double

Dim x1 As Double
Dim x2 As Double
Dim y1 As Double
Dim y2 As Double
Dim z11 As Double
Dim z12 As Double
Dim z21 As Double
Dim z22 As Double

If y < WorksheetFunction.Min(yrng) And x < WorksheetFunction.Min(xrng) Then
    biinterp = "Error: y and x outside of table range, use your eyes"
ElseIf y > WorksheetFunction.Max(yrng) And x < WorksheetFunction.Min(xrng) Then
    biinterp = "Error: y and x outside of table range, use your eyes"
ElseIf y < WorksheetFunction.Min(yrng) And x > WorksheetFunction.Max(xrng) Then
    biinterp = "Error: y and x outside of table range, use your eyes"
ElseIf y > WorksheetFunction.Max(yrng) And x > WorksheetFunction.Max(xrng) Then
    biinterp = "Error: y and x outside of table range, use your eyes"
ElseIf x < WorksheetFunction.Min(xrng) Then
    biinterp = "Error: x outside of table range (take a min value for y)"
ElseIf x > WorksheetFunction.Max(xrng) Then
    biinterp = "Error: x outside of table range (take a max value for y)"
ElseIf y > WorksheetFunction.Max(yrng) Then
    biinterp = "Error: y outside of table range (take a max value for x)"
ElseIf y < WorksheetFunction.Min(yrng) Then
    biinterp = "Error: y outside of table range (take a min value for x)"
else "my function here"
end if 
end function
```

If I enter x or y outside the table range I get a #VALUE! error in the cell, but I can't understand why it won't evaluate the else if conditions.

[EDIT] I discovered that since I wished to output a string or double I had to change the dimension for biinterp to string to allow a number or text to be output.

Comment: There seems to be a worksheet function `IsError()`. Did you try this?

Comment: What do you mean by did I try it? I understand that this returns true/false if an error occurs in the cell (which it does and so is true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have an error in one of the cells that comprise `xrng` or `yrng` (which I'm assuming is the case because you seem to suggest this error only occurs when you're outside the value range), then this should give you a starter:

```
Function biinterp(x, y, xrng As Range, yrng As Range)

Dim x_out As Boolean
Dim y_out As Boolean

x_out = x < WorksheetFunction.Min(xrng) Or x > WorksheetFunction.Max(xrng)
y_out = y < WorksheetFunction.Min(yrng) Or y > WorksheetFunction.Max(yrng)

If x_out And y_out Then
    biinterp = "Error: y and x outside of table range"
ElseIf x_out Then
    biinterp = "Error: x outside of table range"
ElseIf y_out Then
    biinterp = "Error: y outside of table range"
Else
    biinterp = "no error - answer is ..."
End If

End Function
```

Comment: I can confirm that it works for all values within the table range. 
The way I want the errors to display will be different depending on whether it is above or below the xrng or yrng (I want it to be very easy for people to use, minimal thought on their part). 
So with this in mind I would have:
    X_low and X_high variables one for x<min and one for x>max (and the same for y). From this I would essentially have exactly what I have currently except the statements would be replaced with the boolean variables. I will try this tomorrow, but can you explain why this works?

Comment: What you really mean is: *why does this work where yours doesn't?* And to be honest, I can't really tell you without seeing the actual code you're using together with a minimal sample x/y range.

Comment: I will be trying this later today so I will confirm success or not at that point. But to further clarify I was rather asking what does creating the boolean variables vs just putting those lines into the if statement achieve? Does it somehow evaluate it differently?

Comment: Oh, sorry. No, not at all. It merely makes it easier to read.

Comment: I was about to ask you to review my post and it clicked why it wasn't working. I had dimensioned biinterp as a double when it needs to be a string to allow a number or text to be output.

Comment: Oh! Well I'm glad you found it. Hopefully my answer in some way helped or at least gave you an idea of making it more readable. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the error stops the works even if you have provided an alternate.  For example, VBA can't answer "which is smaller: 1 or 1 divided by 0?" because merely attempting to divide 1 by 0 causes a program-stopping error.

Avoiding this is an entire practice called "error handling", which you can control with the statements...

> on error resume next  'This causes VBA to pretend errors don't happen and move along.  Dangerous!

and

> on error goto 0  'This restores the default VBA error protocol: stop the program and offer to debug.

Comment: So from what I understand of this, you would use this to determine what is causing the error and then I should remedy this? And should this line on error goto 0 be provided after each elseif statement?

Comment: Also can you describe how this might apply in the described situation? I don't see where the error is since the error should only occur if x and y are in the table range (which will allow the formula to be executed and give error. If x or y are outside the table range it should simply give me a text output and I don't see how this results in error.

Comment: there is also "on error goto errorhandling routine" which probably is the best practice...

Comment: Without looking at your workbook to see how the #Value error got to the cell, and without the rest of the subroutine, it's hard to know what's really happening.

Answer (score 0):

A #Value is an extemporaneous error that is otherwise unable to be evaluated. IMHO, the first step in the process is to validate the enteries are valid eg (psudocode) if invalid entry then “err in cell” elseif ... rest of conditions.